# Is there a way to call a variable from a different method?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a BMI calculator and I the only thing that can be in the main function is method calls. Whenever i run the following code, the calculation answer does not print. How can i fix that?

```
public static Double EnterWeight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Your Wieght In Pounds: ");
    double Rweight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    return Rweight;
}

public static double EnterHeight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Your Height in Inches: ");
    double Rheight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    return Rheight;
}

public static double Calculation(double height, double weight)
{
    double BMI = (weight / Math.Pow(height, 2) * 703);
    return BMI;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = EnterName();
    //Console.WriteLine(name);
    double weight = EnterWeight();
    //Console.WriteLine(weight);
    double height = EnterHeight(object sender, EventArgs e);
    //Console.WriteLine(height);
    double BMI = Calculation(height, weight);
    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: ", BMI);
}
```

There are some extra lines in the mine that I used for testing.

The result is just a blank

Comment: Create a getter method that you can use to fetch the BMI value from Main method OR make BMI variable public

Comment: This won't compile.  `EnterWeight` expects two parameters but you are passing no parameters.  `EnterHeight(object sender, EventArgs e)` is not a valid way of calling a method, either.

Comment: Why do you have `object sender` and `EventArgs e` in mtehods that don't require those inputs? The code you've posted wouldn't compile since you're not passing any values for those parameters.

Comment: this code cannot even been compiled. Did you read the error messages from your compiler?

Comment: I realize now that i forgot to remove those parameters. I was trying something else to attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several problems with the code, though they are small. First, you define methods that take in parameters that are not used, like `object sender` and `EventArgs e`. You should only define arguments to a method if they are used inside the method, so you can remove those in your case.

Secondly, when you call `EnterWeight`, you're defining the variables inside the method call, rather than defining them before-hand and then passing them in using the variable names (which would be the way to solve this issue). But since the method doesn't actually require them, they can be removed from the method and therefore removed from the call.

Finally, when writing methods to get strongly-typed input from the user, it is sometimes nice to create a more flexible method that takes in a string used for the "prompt" for the input, and then use the `TryParse` methods in a loop, which continually loops until they enter valid input. This way you can re-use the same method to get a `double` from the user and just pass in different prompts.

For example:

```
private static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

private static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt)
{
    double input;

    // double.TryParse attempts to convert a string into a double, and
    // it returns a bool that indicates success. If it's successful,
    // then the out parameter will contain the converted value. Here
    // we loop until we get a successful result, then we return the value.
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

public static double GetBMI(double height, double weight)
{
    return weight / Math.Pow(height, 2) * 703;
}

private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKeyFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return key;
}

private static void Main()
{
    string name = GetStringFromUser("Enter your name: ");
    double weight = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
    double height = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter your height in inches: ");
    double bmi = GetBMI(height, weight);
    Console.WriteLine($"Thank you, {name}. Your BMI is: {bmi}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Console.WriteLine incorrectly. You need to use {argumentNumber} to indicate what argument to print and where in the string. Considering the following (I had to make some additional adjustments to get your code to compile. However, to answer your direct question, your BMI is not printing out because you are using Console.WriteLine slightly wrong.

```
    public static Double EnterWeight()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Your Wieght In Pounds: ");
        double Rweight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        return Rweight;
    }

    public static double EnterHeight()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Your Height in Inches: ");
        double Rheight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        return Rheight;
    }

    public static double Calculation(double height, double weight)
    {
        double BMI = (weight / Math.Pow(height, 2) * 703);
        return BMI;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string name = EnterName();
        //Console.WriteLine(name);
        double weight = EnterWeight();
        //Console.WriteLine(weight);
        double height = EnterHeight();
        //Console.WriteLine(height);
        double BMI = Calculation(height, weight);

        // Notice the {0}. I tell it where in the string to print the
        // argument I passed in out, and the number indicates which argument 
        // to use. Most of .NET formatting works like this.
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: {0}", BMI); 


    }
```

And additional strategy is to use the $"" string where you can do the following:

```
        Console.WriteLine($"Your BMI is: {BMI}");
```